# Javascript Palindrome Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, palindrome

When I run this function:

```
var isPalindrome = function (string) {
  if (string == string.split('').reverse().join('')) {
    console.log(string + ' is palindrome.');
  }
  else {
    console.log(string + ' is not palindrome.');
  }
}
```

console.log(isPalindrome("phone")) ---> "phone is not a palindrome"

console.log(isPalindrome("anna")) ---> "anna is a palindrome"

It works. However, I am completely puzzled as to why this function will not do the same thing?

```
var isPalindrome = function(string) {
  var stringArray = string.split("");
  var reverseStringArray = string.split("");
  reverseStringArray.reverse();

  if (stringArray == reverseStringArray) {
    console.log("Victory!")
  } else {
    console.log("Defeat")
  }
}
```

console.log(isPalindrome("phone")) ---> "Defeat"

console.log(isPalindrome("anna")) ---> "Defeat"

Any ideas?

Comment: You're comparing two different arrays, which are compared by reference, unlike strings which are compared character by character

Comment: Hmmm okay. Because when I do something similar in Ruby, it works. Is this just because it's Javascript? So two arrays most likely will never be the same in Javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Thanks a ton everyone. This helps a lot. I had no idea arrays in Javascript operated like this.

Comment: *"Is this just because it's Javascript?"* - There are a number of languages that handle arrays in this fashion. Used on arrays, `==` asks "Are these the same object instance?", which is not the same equality test as "Do these two objects contain the same data?".